# Is there way to use two Mysql versions in XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am using XAMPP 1.8.3 with MySql(5.0.11) in the windows machine, as per my requirements I have to use `json_array` to manage database and `json_array` support by MySql(5.7 & Up), Is it possible to use two MySql in XAMPP?
Or
is possible to keep XAMPP as it is and install another independent MySql(5.7 & Up) in machine & use both of theme with the different ports.?

Comment: Sure you can install a different MySQL version independently from XAMPP ...

Comment: 1) your version of XAMPP is ancient - why not upgrade that? Your version of PHP is probably out of date too. 2) According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP 1.8.3 came with MySQL 5.6, so it's odd that you have 5.0.11. 3) yes you can just install another copy of MySQL on your machine and use that for your apps instead.

Comment: @ADyson, if I will install another MySql on the machine, will its effect on XAMPP MySql?

Comment: An alternative is to start looking into Docker, you can have a combination of MySQL and PHP versions on the same machine which you can mix and match depending on the containers that are running (I use Portainer or the PHP API to control this part).

Comment: As I already explained you can two MySQL versions side by side, certainly on windows anyway. They shouldn't affect each other.

Comment: Thank you to all, I have installed different stand-alone Mysql and it's working fine.